# React, add Object.keys to the Object.values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an object, I can extract the object keys and the objects values but how can I add the object keys to my objects values object? Ideally I am aiming to it an object look like,

```
{amount: "x", xParty: "x", yAction: "x", zParty: "x", objectKey: "-ggj34h3j4h3hj4hj3")
```

The object key is a unique value every time so ideally it can be the id. Below is an image of what my object keys and object values look like.

[Objectkeys and below is the Object values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfHwK.png)

below is the code I am working with, when I am filtering the object values and I am unsure of how to add in the objects keys

```
    axios.get('url.json')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({transactionInputs: Object.values(response.data).filter(record =>
                record != null),
            });         
            this.props.setupAll(this.state.transactionInputs);
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: `Object.entries` allows you to grab both key and value at once.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: `map` over the `Object.entries` to return the objects formatted to your requirements.

Comment: @NoobCoder Is my answer to your question correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question at first.

Here is a method to get the output you asked for with the input you gave in the console capture (please paste your formatted code instead of an image for your next questions).

Working example :

```js
const keys = ["-LVtWAzcuQ-Xû1h30_EE", "-LVtWcSRXCqodZpsc-k"]

const data = [
    {
        amount: "q",
        id: 0.083183731088e7076,
        zParty: "q",
        yAction: "q",
        zParty: "q"
    },

    {
        amount: "x",
        id: 0.6899E92257812193,
        zParty: "x",
        yAction: "x",
        zParty: "x"
    }
]

const result = data.map((value, index) => ({
    ...value,
    objectKey: keys[index]
}))

console.log(result)
```